# hilios jQuery countdown in php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to display hilios countdown jquery plugin for each member but same countdown is displaying for all member. [image is showing that the countdown for all memebers is same. pLease help .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyL4v.gif)i am echoeing expiry for all members from database of column with name "expiry" and "expiry" is not echoing hilios countdown for all members

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT d.*, c.* from details as d, customer as c where d.customerId = c.id AND c.cmpId = '$idCompany'";
    /*$sql = "SELECT * from customer where cmpId = '$idCompany' ";*/
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>

 <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <?php echo $row['id'] ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo '<img src="images/'.$row['image'].'"; width="100px"; hieght="100px">' ?>
        <a href="#" class="user-link"><?php echo $row['fname']." ".$row['lname']?></a>
        <span class="user-subhead">Member</span>
      </td>

      <td>
         <?php echo $row['time'] ?>
      </td>

      <td class="text-center countdown">
         <!-- Countdown (please check this countdown where the expiry for each member has to echo but same expiry is echoing for all members)-->
         <span class="label label-default getting-started"></span>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".getting-started").each(function(){
              $('.getting-started').countdown('<?php echo $row["expiry"] ?> ' , function(time) {
                $(this).html(time.strftime('%w wk %d d %H h %M m %S s'));
                });
                })
                //})
        </script>
      </td>

      <td>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['customerName']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#smsModal" class="mobile"><?php echo $row['mobile'] ?></a>
      </td>

      <td style="width: 20%;">
        <a style="float:left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#memberInfo" href="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="table-link clsMemberInfo view">
        <span class="fa-stack">
           <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
        </a>
        <a style="float:left" href="#" class="table-link" id="#save">
         <span class="fa-stack">
           <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
           <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
         </span>
        </a>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="table-link danger delmodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">
           <span class="fa-stack">
             <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
           </span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" class="" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body text-center">
                  <p>Are you Sure you want to Delete ?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <div class="col-lg-7">
                     <form method="post" id="deleteForm">
                       <input type="hidden" id="MemberId" name="MemberId" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">
                       <button type="submit" name="submit" id="yes_btn" class="btn btn-danger yes_btn">Yes</button>
                     </form>
                     <button type="button" id="no_btn" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                   </div>
               </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>                                           
<?php 
  } 
?>
```